# Twitter UserStream auto update with https

Tags: twitter

I am currently connecting to the Twitter User Stream API but it seems that I am not getting updates on my production environment (https), it does work on my staging server though.

Some information that I checked myself already:
- The 2 environments are on the same server so it can not be an IP block.
- A code issue would be possible but unlikely since it works on staging but not on production
- Nginx is configured correctly to allow this on https since it worked before

the only thing I can think of is that Twitter blocked our https connection, we reached a Twitter cap or Twitter got problems streaming to Https.

Is there anyone that encountered this before or that can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this was caused by Twitter who puts an internal (badly documented) limit on connections from a webservice to their UserStream service. (This connection limit is around 20 - 30 connections I think).

A solution that I use now is to poll every 90 seconds to their REST api.